# sabre soap api token access

Tags: soap, access-token, sabre

I am trying to access the sabre soap api for token access. The following is a sample from the sabre website for a request to the sabre soap api:

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId>Client</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId>SWS</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>PCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>1234</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>TokenCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1234</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2015-01-01T00:00:00</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>PCC</Organization>
                <Domain>DOMAIN</Domain>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sws:TokenCreateRQ Version="1.0.0" />
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In the Organization tag above there is a field called PCC.

The sabre website states that PCC is Sabre shorthand for a Pseudo City Code (PCC) that includes an Employee Profile Record (EPR) with Sabre APIs.  However I am not sure where I find the value for PCC for my soap request.

Answer (score 2):

You will be granted a PCC once you become a Sabre customer. 
Once you have an API agreement, you will get an Email with the User/Passcode/PCC combination that you need to use in order to create a SOAP session.

You can get in contact with the sales team through the Contact Us/Become a Sabre customer feature on DevStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Apply for new sabre dev account online and you will get the PCC code which can be found in the sabre account settings

Answer (score 0):

Sabre Team will provide credentials for production as well development

For the development keep the url as https://sws-crt.cert.sabre.com/

Use Username/Password provided from them

Answer (score 0):

For token i use SessionCreateRQ and work fine.
This is example of request.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">abcd.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>PCCHERE</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>6f6794a902589f6a759ad231376e2c3e</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>TRB_0.99863000 1635836545_0</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2021-11-02T09:02:25</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:TimeToLive>2022-11-02T00:00:00</eb:TimeToLive>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>PCCHERE</Organization>
            <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SessionCreateRQ>
        <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="PCCHERE"/>
        </POS>
    </SessionCreateRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>